# typescript inferred type should be object but array is returned

Tags: typescript

I want to write a type-safe function that takes an argument representing a prop that is a primitive or maybe a more specific object with values of the same primitive. for example `t=number` or `t={x:number}` or `t={x:number,y:number}`

so for example prop named grid which is `number` but can be specified with `horizontal|vertical` fields, so valid input would be `grid=10` or `grid={horizontal:10}` or `grid={vertical:10}` or `grid={horizontal:10,vertical:10}`

a working implementation:

```
export type Primitive = string | number | boolean | null | undefined;
export type PossiblySpecifyAxis<T> = T | SpecifyAxis<T>;
export type SpecifyAxis<T> = { horizontal?: T; vertical?: T };

const parsePossiblyAxis = <
  Prop extends PossiblySpecifyAxis<Primitive>,
  Default extends NonNullable<Primitive> | undefined = undefined
>(
  prop: Prop,
  defaultValue?: Default
): {
  horizontal: Prop extends Primitive ? Prop : Prop extends { horizontal: infer V } ? V : Default;
  vertical: Prop extends Primitive ? Prop : Prop extends { vertical: infer V } ? V : Default;
} => {
  // does not matter
  ///////////////////////////////////////// 
  return {} as any
};
// works great
const c1 = parsePossiblyAxis(10) // => {horizontal: 10; vertical: 10;}
const c2 = parsePossiblyAxis({horizontal:5} as const,10) // => {horizontal: 5; vertical: 10;}
const c3 = parsePossiblyAxis(10,30) // => {horizontal: 10; vertical: 10;}
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKUCWBbTNMBuqAvHAM4xYB2A5nAD5xUCu2ARsFA3GxBADbAAhlW4t+-bsyoATYADNMVYDIDcAKFCRYCZKjQQyZTG36IAyigDGmeYgCCITGQA8AFQB8cUm+6XgNnaOzu4eGlrQ8EgocP6BDk6unt5wAN5wABbQmABeEFQwQvwA-ABccG6qcESwmFZFZRVwAL4a6lb5FHBgQlBkwAZGJmbBZCku6nDoUBBgcKAwwLJjg8amFta2CSEYOHiEwB4ANJNwACIKQsz88AtLMmMAcvmP1-xCpsAuu7j4RF6MaRyRTKGQpIEKJQqdQeAAUpzAMzA5QwsxOU2BVxuADUisxgI0LvIsTB1ABKcqpU5ZLB5ApFFFI+YgRbLaZ7P6oYrTWZwRm8u5s9I03L5Qr8cpKeScODYlpwbly8pEkkaKY1fD1CU8uaCh7s34HBU6vkmvVjdIauoMuBSmVy5rGpXnS7XGAaR3ELxUqYAel9cAAVmMcGBBNgloV8Pk4DIIMAyFQAOTwKDCCSIODYIQwRanf0FwtF4sl0vFuCnWxwWHRYAQeTdJnEZtwABEEDYgYCMFbZLSpymaZgzCgomF2Tp4vKiNmxQAdCLJ0UFdzMW7cfx8UdqpxNTaZ2B51atSvY66cXjUI6hGMRIg1fLgPx+v2poPgMPR2lMhOxfumcUq7njAG5bjutRatOAFAcS66XvKN5wHeD7NOorTqP6cAAO7QAA1mMNBpjm7SdPAVgAIwpD0fQDIYawjIksLkQADH2mFemki5-tqLFVMeNq8ahHRUF0VgAExUb0-SrMM2xkLCqRcfSEoAKzXmMwkUEcLFsQGHGKb+ynlCpfG7taPHMaoQmkXAVgAMySTRMnrKMTHMUcdmsXA7HekpU5wLx4F7hZVnqEAA)

Now i want to make this function more generic, so instead of specifying `horizontal|vertical` hardcoded i would like to except this type as a generic as well:

```
export type Primitive = string | number | boolean | null | undefined;
export type PossiblySpecific<Prop, Spec extends string> = Prop | { [key in Spec]: Prop };
//example: type t1 = PossiblySpecific<10,'x'|'y'> // => '10' | {x:10,y:10}

const parsePossiblySpecific = <
  Spec extends string[],
  Prop extends PossiblySpecific<Primitive, Spec[number]>,
  Default extends NonNullable<Primitive> | undefined = undefined
>(
  prop: Prop,
  fields: Spec,
  defaultValue?: Default
): {
  ////instead of 
  // horizontal: Prop extends Primitive ? Prop : Prop extends { horizontal: infer V } ? V : Default;
  // vertical: Prop extends Primitive ? Prop : Prop extends { vertical: infer V } ? V : Default;
  //// use 'Spec' generic to infer the type of the fields and construct the return type 
  [key in keyof Spec]: Prop extends Primitive ? Prop : Prop extends { [key in keyof Spec]: infer V } ? V : Default;
} => {
  // doesn't matter
  }
};

const c1 = parsePossiblySpecific(10,["horizontal","vertical"]) // => 10[] => Wrong! why this is the resulted type??
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKUCWBbTNMBuqAvHAM4xYB2A5nAD5xUCu2ARsFA3GxBADbAAhlW4t+-bsyoATYADNMVYDIDcAKFCRYCZKjQQyZTG36IAyigDGmRVYA8GCGAA0cS8CtxQMYLLLklEo0AHxwpE5g3ADecADaANbAiHBK7tYAugBc6FDOcAC+GkgoCACM4eiGxqYW1raYDmUADC4A5CBt9G2IbWEA9P3hYW0tbTEgWS0uiFPNBerqVhBUFHBgQlBkwAZGJmYeNnaV9upw6Z7eIL7+gdQ0cRkuZ7n5Pn4yAbs1B-V2jlhcPgiG5DnEWOxOBkQs9zgARBRCZj8eDvW4AORW6OR-CEpmAAJweEIwDCjGkckUyhklQpCiUKnUIQAFC8wHkwDlIrC4IpgPxPjlDjzKUiUQA1IT8ZjAAD8OQR8jFMHUAEoctEXoNBkoKMIaRB5HAtUMABbQTAALxWMClXI5Vxun1yROBqFlryi9re1w+AVi5qw1qotv4OSU8k4cHFhTgHpjCsRyJgGnOgzgRFgjTtnsdfpdQJJcdz3qiaOdsUz+CsOYjUZjBWLCbgiuVqbg2qGzG2cDah3GND8nEaCAgqSoka4MFNqBKqENCBnvMw-OdIhpy1WlGYVng09QUGAMGYUFEc+N50SyXHcCSiAXh2yufLX0BxKIxcicFLedusSvKRpHeD6ZOGE71rG8bfi2SYohojbEGEmrnLYcDMnOC7svkxA4XAABEEBsAAVp4MB4aqcDIecHZDAAAjAZAALSYDQVDQLOEAyBAWSKCALxpkMh7HqelFwIGVo2jmWFgLKAB04nBqGcYeqKyaStKwBuFW2ZhusHJydpNaSLKKmwTA6kyoU7YCXAQknqIfICmQsnYEIYDMsyjkyBRiF6c4clxF5GTKXAqkSlKMpuNEBSqtZcCbmsh4BKQXnOYeMg7sAHnssABBuF5PlhMysSyaVOV5fEQU5NJAVBSFYXmRFqAxVFMVxXZIlJe2jb8j2VE2fRTEsWxh6jlxPGYHx1E0bZR72aJCmSbp0n1WZFmaRmnDVlJDomaFa1NVZ-EzR1Dkrk5LluR5BXDH5UR7Q162xcdCXwEllSpbJ6WZdlh4VTdvnFXApWyeVbiBedMhPitD0HRphSqq1z3Tads1kN16hFIsr3xRUpAbFsOzVPsdSeA0VjMtMcR4YtIZSnhLh4YZ9MZBR6a+S0jy3QA6nktAAIRwAA7qaKTTpgAQS4uB7AGQyYqLoKAmUAA)

In simple words: i am asking: why does:

```
// works pefectly fine: object is returned
{
  horizontal: Prop extends Primitive ? Prop : Prop extends { horizontal: infer V } ? V : Default;
  vertical: Prop extends Primitive ? Prop : Prop extends { vertical: infer V } ? V : Default;
}

// returns an array - WHY?
{
  [key in keyof Spec]: Prop extends Primitive ? Prop : Prop extends { [key in keyof Spec]: infer V } ? V : Default;
}
```

to see full working examples see ts-playgrounds. the js works great but the inferred type is wrong. this should be a stupid mistake but I can't find it. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would change is the return type of the function. Since `Spec` is a tuple, mapping over it will also result in a tuple. Instead you could map over the union of the contents of `Spec.`

```
{
  [key in Spec[number]]: Prop extends Primitive 
    ? Prop 
    : Prop extends { [key in keyof Spec]: infer V } 
      ? V 
      : Default;
}
```

The other problem is the inference of `Spec`. The way you specified the argument `fields`, `Spec` will always be infered as just `string[]` instead of a tuple like `["horizontal","vertical"]`.

To fix this, we can use the spread syntax.

```
const parsePossiblySpecific = <
  Spec extends string[],
  Prop extends PossiblySpecific<Primitive, Spec[number]>,
  Default extends NonNullable<Primitive> | undefined = undefined
>(
  prop: Prop,
  fields: [...Spec],
  defaultValue?: Default
)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKUCWBbTNMBuqAvHAM4xYB2A5nAD5xUCu2ARsFA3GxBADbAAhlW4t%20-bsyoATYADNMVYDIDcAKFCRYCZKjQQyZTG36IAyigDGmRVYA8GCGAA0cS8CtxQMYLLLklEo0AHxwpE5g3ADecADaANbAiHBK7tYAugBc6FDOcAC%20GkgoCACM4eiGxqYW1raYDmUADC4A5CBt9G2IbWEA9P3hYW0tbTEgWS0uiFPNBerqVhBUFHBgQlBkwAZGJmYeNnaV9upw6Z7eIL7%20gdQ0cRkuZ7n5Pn4yAbs1B-V2jlhcPgiG5DnEWOxOBkQs9zgARBRCZj8eDvW4AORW6OR-CEpmAAJweEIwDCjGkckUyhklQpCiUKnUIQAFC8wHkwDlIrC4IpgPxPjk4gA6UWHJ4vSlIlEANSE-GYwAA-DkEfJpTB1ABKHLRF6DQZKCjCGkQeRwfVDAAW0EwAC8VjB5VyOVcbp9ckTgagla8oi63tcPgFYjasA6qE7%20DklPJOHAZYU4L7E6rEciYBpzoM4ERYI1nX63cHPUCScmiwGomiPbE8-grIXY-HEwUK6m4GqNVm4AahsxtnA2odxjQ-JxGggIKkqHGuDAragSqgzQhF7zMPyPSIactVpRmFZ4AvUFBgDBmFBRMuLedEskZxcrODWBwoBlskWa19AcSiBXIjgKti1uWJ7xSNIkkQVdxRjWcWyTFMgM7dMUQ0NtiDCPVzlsOBmWXVd2XyYgSLgAAiCA2AAK08GAyK1OBsPOXshgAARgMgAFpMBoKhoCXCAZAgLJFBAF5syGM8LyvRi4DDe1HULIiwCVYV5IjKNk19KUMzlBVgDcesC2jdYOVUozG0kJVtNQmA9MVQoewkuApMvUQ%20QFMhhWwIQwGZZkPJkBjMNM5xVLiQKMi0uAdNleVFTcaICi1Jy4D3NYzwCUhAq8s8ZEPYB-PZYACDcQLgrCZlYlFYVitK%20JIpyZTwsi6LYrs%20LUGSxLktS1yZMyuAhACEREB7Nt%20UHJjnPYrieL4s8pyEkTMDE5iWJc883Nk9TFJM5S2ts%20yDNzTgGyU11rJio7Osc8SNv69zN087zfP88rhlCqIrva46Uvu9L4EG7Lns%20YU8oKoqz3qj6QqquAarqtwItBz8Dp%20m79MKLUev%209bHs2kaRqoMaXgWIpFkBtKKlIDYth2ap9jqTwGisZlpjiMjdsjeUyJcMiLN5jIGJzEKWkeT6AHU8loABCOAAHcrRSBdMACNW11PYAyAzFRdBQaygA)

Comment: Thank You! wondeful ;) the first mistake is quite stupid, but I didn't know about the spread syntax.. thanks!